# .Net Framework Identity Server 3 - Windows Authentication

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication, identityserver3, .net-framework-version

We are using Identity Server 3 in our tool that has the following structure. One (AngularJs) Spa with 10 Web APIs . We use the WindowsAuthWebHost mini project to do the windows handshake to get the windows(domain) identity of the user, based on which we build a complex(with custom claims) token that it's used by the client Web APIs. All the 10 Web APIs have anonymous authentication set in the IIS. And it works smoothly.

Now, we are trying to expose this tool outside the company network and a perquisite is to have windows authentication on all the Web APIs in the IIS. If we set this time of authentication, now all the calls are unauthorized.

Do you know if there is a way to keep the same flow, but also validated the windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication will not work outside of the network. The user needs to have a valid user account in your domain (username/password), or even a local account on your IIS server.
Note that NTLM doesn't work through some proxy servers, so this is one reason that Windows AuthN isn't used so much on the public internet.

To achieve your requirement you could use the form authentication with active directory.you may need to enable both form and anonymous authentication. then create deny authorization rule for anonymous users and allow rule for all users.

[How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650308(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)